# disable event handler in c# on textchanged

Tags: c#, events, handler

I want to be able to disable or enable textchanged event when I need to.
I have made my function, but I need to dismiss event handler, how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           //something
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This to add the event

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
```

this to remove the event

```
textBox1.TextChanged -= new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Or just the method name

This to add the event

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

this to remove the event

```
textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I find  '-= new' very confusing. How does .net know what event handler to remove when it is 'new'?

Answer (score 2):

simply un-register the event

```
 yourEvent-= YourFunction
```

and if you want to register again

```
 yourEvent+= YourFunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe textchange event. Put following line of code at you want.

```
textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
```